# Android Studio App crashes on run after successful build and apk installation

Tags: android, android-studio

This is the simple java code used by me on login screen. App closes itself after the splash screen which I applied. It doesnt go any further. what to do?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_email);
EditText password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_password);
Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
int counter=3;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); }

//Login Button Code

public void onBtn(View v){
if(username.getText().toString().equals("shubham.goyal1210@gmail.com")&&
(password.getText().toString().equals("shubham")))
{
Toast.makeText(this, "Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
else {
Toast.makeText(this, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
counter--;
if(counter==0){ loginButton.setEnabled(false); }
else 
{ 
Toast.makeText(this, counter+" attempts left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
}}

//Sign Up Button Code

public void linkSign(View v){
Intent intent = new Intent(this, signupActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
}}
```

Comment: it looks like this is your first question....for an error like this you'll need to at least post, from logcat, what the specific error is you're seeing.  If it's a NullPointerException (as usually is case for something like this), you need to show that you at least identified what was  null when crash occurred.

Comment: I was initializing the EditText and Button at the wrong place and yesI am a rookie.. I corrected that thing and it worked.. Thanxx :)

Answer (score 2):

move

```
EditText username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_email);
EditText password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_password);
Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
```

after `setContentView` while keeping reference variable outside `oncreate` because views are only available in the UI hierarchy of the activity after invocation of `setContentView`

```
EditText username;
EditText password;
Button loginButton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_email);
    password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_password);
    loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I corrected that thing and the app worked.. thanxx :)

Answer (score 0):

You initialize `EditText` and `Button` view on wrong place ,you need to initialize it inside `onCreate` method like below.

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    EditText username;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_email);
       ...

    }


}
```